Impossible to add debug bar or telescope
Impossible to add the debug bar or Telescope, If I use composer command, I have this error :

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the
post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255

and this error :

Fatal error: Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure does not exist. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/bootstrap/app.php(7): Illuminate\Foundation\Application::__callStatic('configure', Array, basePath: '/Applications/M...') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/public/index.php(16): require_once('/Applications/M...') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php on line 86

I'm working under MacBook Pro Sonoma with last version of Laravel.
Composer version 2.5.7 2023-05-24 15:00:39
Any idea please ?

Have you tried running composer dumpauto?

Thank you for your reply.  I did it just right now, but same problem :  Fatal error: Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::configure does not exist. in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:86 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/bootstrap/app.php(7): Illuminate\Foundation\Application::__callStatic('configure', Array, basePath: '/Applications/M...') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phyclexdev310724/public/... my site is not longer available again...

Try to delete both vendor and composer.lock and reinstall dependencies with composer install

Thank you for your reply.  I deleted composer.lock and the folder vendor, I did composer install and I h ave exactly the same problem

Try to run composer update --no-scripts and then composer dump-autoload

Thank you for your reply.  composer update --no-scripts works but composer dump-autoload I have the same problem.  It's a big problem for me because I have to install composer require laravel/ui and it's impossible for me.

What is your Laravel version?

Laravel Framework 11.7.0 but I don't know why in composer.lock I have         "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
